# sudoers file NOPASSWD entries ignored?

Tags: unix, sudo

My sudoers file is seemingly ignored. I appended these two lines via vim (`sudo visudo`):

```
myusername ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/networksetup -setsocksfirewallproxy
myusername ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/networksetup -setsocksfirewallproxystate
```

but when I run either command I am prompted to type a password:

```
$ sudo -n networksetup -setsocksfirewallproxy "Wi-Fi" localhost 3000
sudo: a password is required
```

Comment: bash isn't responsible for looking at what's in your `sudoers` file -- it's the `sudo` binary that does that lookup; you could reproduce this bug with a different shell or no shell at all (as an example of the no-shell case, consider the following Python: `subprocess.call(['sudo', 'networksetup', '-setsocksfirewallproxy', 'Wi-Fi', 'localhost', '3000'])`).

Comment: When you inquire, the person that notifies is the last person to comment, not whoever downvoted. That said, to throw in my own opinion as to quality: I *do* think this question is eligible for close-as-offtopic (inasmuch as it's about usage of standard UNIX tools, not software development), but don't see any particular reason to downvote it (which is for "unclear or not useful, or not showing research effort"; none of those obviously apply).

Answer (score 5):

The sudoers file only looks for exactly the command you give it.  You are trying to run it with extra parameters that are not defined in the sudoers file; That is why you are getting prompted for a password.

Try something like this:

```
myusername ALL = NOPASSWD : /usr/sbin/networksetup -setsocksfirewallproxy *, /usr/sbin/networksetup -setsocksfirewallproxystate *
```

Comment: *nod*. The OP might be confused because the zero-arguments case has an implicit wildcard, unless `""` is explicitly appended to disable that behavior.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy yes, pretty much describes what happened. Thank you also for your edit, I didn't realise that sudoers had nothing to do with bash.